# Why do these borders overlap?

Tags: css

Using CSS, these borders overlap on the bottom. I'm using the outline property. I'm displaying images in a grid, but want the grid with a border. I will not know ahead of time how many items are in the grid, there may be 1, there may be 2, 3, 14, etc.

[See the overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzmuy.png)

Here is my CSS

```
.products {display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;width:100%;margin-top:75px;}

.product {outline: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);width:33.33%;display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-ms-flex-direction:column;-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-webkit-box-direction:normal;flex-direction:column;}

.product img {image-rendering:crisp-edges;-webkit-image-rendering:crisp-edges;}

.product a::after {text-transform:none;content:attr(data-productname);font-size:16px;color:#000;margin:10px 0;opacity:.5;pointer-events:none;text-align:center;display:block;}
```

HTML (using in Laravel Blade):

```
    <div class="products">
@foreach ($product_items as $product)
<div class="product all {{$product->menu_id}}"><a href="{{url('product') . '/' . $product->id}}" data-productname="{{$product->name}}"><img src="{{url($product->file_name)}}"></a></div>
@endforeach
```

The output looks like this:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46yRF.jpg)

But I can't figure out how to get rid of those pesky overlapping outlines. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add maring same as the outline or used border instead

Comment: Adding a 1px margin makes the outline thicker and also makes the grid go into two columns and not three. Also, I can't use border or nth-child properties because I don't know how many items will be in the grid

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make the outline property affect one side only, hence the overlapping.

I would recommend using the border or box-shadow properties. Using border, we can set `box-sizing` to `border-box` and so make sure the border stay inside the div.

```
.product {
    width: 33.33%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-direction: column;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    border-left-width: 0;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```

Next, we need to add the left border for the first element of each row. For that you will need to wrap every group of 3 items inside a div, which you can easily do using PHP.

```
.groupe-of-3-products .product:first-child {
    border-left-width: 1px;
}
```

Finally, we need to add the bottom border for the last row.

```
.groupe-of-3-products:last-child .product {
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
```

Here is a [live example](https://codepen.io/remeus/pen/JZxYYy).